# PHP Session data lost after jQuery POST request

Tags: php, session, post

I know that this question seems like it is the same that it has been asked a lot of times, but please keep reading.

The problem is, like the title suggest, the session data is not being saved in my PHP scripts when I make a POST request to another page.

- Yes, all scripts has `session_start();` at the very first line.
- Yes, I have checked if the session_id is the same, and it is.
- The apache log isn't showing any errors (I have it showing all
  errors)
- I tested if sessions were working creating simple pages for creating/reading sessions variables and it worked. It is when I use POST requests when it behaves strange.

Both scripts are in the same server.

I'll show my code edited just to show the idea of what it does.

**Script A**

```
<?
session_start();

echo session_id()."<br>";
print_r($_SESSION);

require_once __DIR__ . '/include/config.php';

ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);

session_set_cookie_params(
    0,
    ini_get('session.cookie_path'),
    ini_get('session.cookie_domain'),
    isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']),
    true
);

$_SESSION['haygsdb18'] = true;
$_SESSION['user_name'] = '';
$_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$_SESSION['REMOTE_ADDR'] = md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$include_path =  str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',__DIR__);

?>

$.post(
    "<?=$include_path?>/include/ScriptB.php",
    {OTP: OTP},
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
);
```

**Script B**

```
<?
session_start();

$msg = session_id()."\n";
$msg .= print_r($_SESSION,true);
exit($msg);
?>
```

This way I'm debugging. The script B shows the same session id, but no session variables.

I have lost my mind trying to figure it out. Another thing that is freaking me is that the same script (exactly the same, copy pasted) in another folder in the server works perfectly.

Please help... I run out of ideas.

**UPDATE: MORE DEBUG INFO**

I took a look to the `sess` file created by php using `tail -f` in the terminal. When script A is loaded the variables are written in the file, and when the AJAX call is made the file is emptied (not deleted, just emptied).

When the Script A executes `$_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);` the sess file is written with `HTTP_USER_AGENT|s:32:"2589a220583546006658f54ada687b45";`, but when Script B executes `$_SESSION['TEST'] = '1';` the all the content off the sess file is replaced with `C1Hw6hhbpX-jWhvbRfz_reKX4tT66bcNpYGLGzxEg7I.`

**LOT OF DEBUGGING.. FOUND A STRANGE THING**

I compared how the session_handler was writing the sess file in the other systems where I am using the same login script. In the other systems the Script A and the Script B are writing encrypted info into the file. The problem is the in this particular system the Script A is not writing the file with any encryption, but the Script B is.

I'm suspecting that Script B is expecting that the session info is encrypted, so because it is not it can't read the variables and they are gone. The same occurs when trying to keep alive the variables from Script B to Script A.

So now my question comes to this, how is it possible that Script A and Script B are using different session_write handlers when I haven't told them to do it? How con I force them to use the same?

Comment: we need the code of the script checkOTP.php to check..

Comment: It is the Script B.. i will edit the question

Comment: Try, instead of using exit, which might cause your session to be prematurely closed, just to echo whatever you're debugging with. I've been driven insane too many times debugging stuff, the `die()` statement somewhere in the code interfered with the persisting of the session.

Comment: It didn't change the result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally got it.

As I posted in the question, the problem was that the session_handler was writing the sess file with different encoding. So both scripts where trying to read the file and none of them could read the variables correctly.

I had a `php.ini` file that was used to change the default charset with the directive

```
default_charset = "iso-8859-1"
```

I had to use this directive beacuse some changes the server admin did. I created a `.user.ini` file in the root directory to use the ISO encoding, but I forgot to remove this `php.ini` file.

Probably the charset was messing with the encoding/decoding process because of the `php.ini` file was affecting just one of the scripts (the other one was in a different folder). So I removed that directive and the problem disappeared.

Hopefully this question will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your session is not being written to disk or whatever storage you are using, because the script execution may not be completed when you make the ajax call.

You can use session_write_close() function to persist session data to the storage (most probably your /tmp/ folder)
http://php.net/manual/tr/function.session-write-close.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id()."<br>";
print_r($_SESSION);


ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);

session_set_cookie_params(0,ini_get('session.cookie_path'),ini_get('session.cookie_domain'),isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']),true);

$_SESSION['haygsdb18'] = true;
$_SESSION['user_name'] = '';
$_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$_SESSION['REMOTE_ADDR'] = md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
//write the session before the script execution ends
session_write_close();

$include_path =  str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',__DIR__);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $.post("scriptB.php", {OTP: "OTP"}, function(data) {
                    alert(data);});

            });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my output;

```
tdiiqame0i4ldshc8m20n8d9o6
Array
(
    [haygsdb18] => 1
    [user_name] => 
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => bc9d9d38aa0626db612842a1e0d09ea9
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => f528764d624db129b32c21fbca0cb8d6
)
```

Comment: I think I tried doing that. I will try again tomorrow and tell you how did it go.

Comment: It didn't work. I am suspecting a problem with server configuration.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Maybe it would be a permission issue, check if your user -who is running the webserver- has permissions to write file to the session.save_path.  Also you can check if the session file is created in your session save path when the script is executed.

Comment: All file permissions are OK. The file is being written/read, the problem (as I updated the question) is that the file is encoded in different ways in each script.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set session time:

```
define("SESSION_TIME_EXPIRED",'172800');    
session_set_cookie_params(SESSION_TIME_EXPIRED); 
session_name('user');
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

doesnt `session_set_cookie_params(0, ...)` create session which expires immediately?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: Actually the value 0 creates a session that last untils the browser is closed. http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem.
I was using custom sessions.
use this

```
session_regenerate_id();
```

NOT

```
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

use this just after starting session